# Manually trigger a build for a branch outside of the safelist (or within blocklist) in travis-ci

Tags: travis-ci

If I create a safelist of branches in my travis config and omit a particular branch A (or equivalently if I put branch A into a blocklist), can I manually trigger a build on branch A? The plan is to allow broken code to be committed to branch A, but before merging back to a stable branch, do a ci test. I just don't want to see a bunch of failed builds. Maybe I'm saving some small amount of electricity for them. Also I don't to add a bunch of noise by adding `[skip travis]` to every commit message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can navigate to any build of the project in Travis, click on "More options" > "Trigger build," then select the branch from there.